SPFx webpack without framework i try to import a javascript build
I am trying to import in a SPFx a build of my code, I used different builds but all the time gulp serve tells me the same (unexpected token in different line) 
I tried import the build with:


require("./assets/index-d047dcd4.js");



import "./assets/index-d047dcd4.js";



<script type="module" src="./assets/index-040e3dba.js"></script>



but all the time said the same error
I have discovered that the openbim-components modules are the problem, I can import other builds.
i need help too resolve or understand how i can import builds to the SPFx

Are you sure the NodeJS, Npm, Gulp, Yeoman and SPFx versions you have installed are compatible? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/set-up-your-development-environment

yes, I found out that it's because of the openbim-components modules, with leaflet i havent got problems
